# Suppose that $f: D \to D$ is analytic with $f(0) = 0$. Show $f$ assumes all values $z$ with $|z| \leq 1/2$ with given assumption

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f: D \to D$ is analytic with $f(0) = 0$. Suppose that $|f(z)| \geq 1/6$ for all $z$ with $|z| = 1/4$. Show that $f$ assumes all values $z$ such that $|z| < 1/6$.

Thoughts so far: I know that holomorphic functions don't necessarily preserve semi-connectedness, so there's no obvious reason why this should be true. The problem seems set up to apply the Schwartz Lemma, but I'm not sure how to use it to prove what we want.

Context: I'm studying for a qual, which is tomorrow, so if you could indicate how to approach this problem I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Comments to the question (v1): 1. What is $D$? 2. Title and main body questions seem slightly different.

Comment: $D$ is most probably the open unit disk in the complex plane.